# Django: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'create'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have two classes in `models.py`

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accounts = models.ManyToManyField(Account, blank=True)
```

Now in my `views.py` I have:

```
def create_account(request):
    account = Account(symbol=request.POST['symbol'])
    account.save()
```

However, when the form that calls the `create_function` is successfully submitted, my Django debug mode throws the error: `'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'create'`, and `SELECT * FROM` the relevant table in my database confirms that no row has been added.

After searching this error online, I can confirm that this probably has to do with the fact that the `Profile` class is many-to-many associated with the `Account` class and that I should be creating `Account` objects differently, however I am not sure how to do it correctly.

Comment: I think the error is not from your ```create_account()``` function, rather there should be some code which tries to save your Profile model and raising error.